# Providing command line arguments for an executable through a shell script

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, scripting, ksh

Suppose I have an executable **xyz** that takes a variable number of command-line arguments, and a wrapper Korn shell script **xyz.ksh**.  Is there an easy way to pass all of the shell script arguments as-is to the executable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use:

```
"$@"
```

for correct parameter expansion in all cases. This behaviour is the same in both bash and ksh.

Most of the time, $* or $@ will give you what you want. However, they expand parameters with spaces in it. "$*" gives you all parameters reduced down to one. "$@" gives you what was actually passed to the wrapper script.

See for yourself (again, under either bash or ksh):

```
[tla ~]$ touch file1 file2 space\ file
[tla ~]$ ( test() { ls $*; }; test file1 file2 space\ file )
ls: cannot access space: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
file1  file2
[tla ~]$ ( test() { ls $@; }; test file1 file2 space\ file )
ls: cannot access space: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
file1  file2
[tla ~]$ ( test() { ls "$*"; }; test file1 file2 space\ file )
ls: cannot access file1 file2 space file: No such file or directory
[tla ~]$ ( test() { ls "$@"; }; test file1 file2 space\ file )
file1  file2  space file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the $* variable: 
http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#commandlineargs

It's otherwise known as $@ in bash, I think.

Comment: Slightly wrong - they function the same in both bash and ksh

Comment: @MikeyB Wrong, at least for bash. `$*` passes all parameters as a single string, wheres `$@` passes all parameter as a list of separate strings. From the bash manual: `"$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c..."` and ` `$@` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`. There are cases where you need need to use `$*` whereas `$@` will not work. For bash related stuff use `man bash` and search for the terms you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use the $* variable.  Try this script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo $*
```

and then invoke the script with something like:

```
scriptname a b c foobar
```

Your output will be:

```
a b c foobar
```

Comment: Good answer, but slightly wrong.